# In sandbox mode, can you bake a block with a specific timestamp?

Tags: baking, smart-contracts, sandbox

I am testing a smart contract that enforces time delays on state transitions. I want to be able to run the `bake` command and have the latest block have a particular Unix timestamp (e.g. for 1 day ahead of the current block). Is there an argument I can pass in to specify the time of the newly baked block?